# If-else in where clause SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL-Server 2008 how do I achieve the following objective -

```
select * from student 
where 
(
   (if studentId is not null then  studentId='x')
   else
   (firstName='abc' and age > 26)
)
```

I would like to avoid re-writing the entire select clause for either conditions separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an `OR` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE
    studentId = 'x'
    OR (firstname = 'abc' AND age > 26)
```

Comment: I think you need to add an explicit `AND studentId is null` to the second part of the OR (assuming I'm reading the question correctly, the parentheses seem a bit odd), but yes, this is the answer.

Comment: @lc. - no, not needed. UPD: sorry, agree - in this particular wording you are correct.

Comment: @RogerWolf It depends on how you read the `else` in the question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` statement in the `where` clause.  You could almost think of a `case` statement like SQL's "set based" version of an `if` statement -

```
select * 
from student 
where 
    case 
        when studentId is not null and studentId = 'x'
            then 1
        when firstName='abc' and age > 26
            then 2
        else 0
    end <> 2
```

More on the `case` statement-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

http://sqlschool.modeanalytics.com/intermediate/case.html